# Get result from raw SQL statments with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do some statments with PDO and Laravel 5.5.

```
public static function getNbCoach() {
    return DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateur WHERE id_statut = 2 AND actif = true');
}
```

The result is :

```
array:1 [▼
   0 => {#186 ▼
      +"count": 0
   }
]
```

How can I do to get the result (which is 0 in this case) instead of the array.

I already tried that but doesn't works.

```
public static function getNbCoach() {
    return DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateur WHERE id_statut = 2 AND actif = true')->get();
}

public static function getNbCoach() {
    return DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateur WHERE id_statut = 2 AND actif = true')[0];
}
```

Thank's for help !

Comment: what is the result if you use this sql request `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateur`. Are you sure you have a user with this id_status  and active ? If you have no result you have a problem with your SGBD otherwise you might just need some more data in your database.

Comment: there is no select() method in PDO. you are using Laravel's DB, not PDO here

Comment: I don't have data into my database but even without data, result must be 0 no ?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I cant use PDO ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database

Comment: add ->get() at the end

Comment: you can but it depends on what you really need

Comment: @Indra I get an error : Call to a member function get() on array

Comment: Sorry , DB::RAW('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateur WHERE id_statut = 2 AND actif = true')->get(); or Utilisateur::where('id_status', 2)->where('actif', true)->get();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->get()` always returns a multidimensional array. There are two ways you can do this:

<strike>Use `->first()` instead:</strike>

```
    return DB::select('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM utilisateur WHERE id_statut = 2 AND actif = true')->first();
```

Or use the QueryBuilder methods, which will return an actual number instead of an object or array:

```
    return DB::table('utilisateur')
      ->where('id_statut', 2)
      ->where('actif', true)
      ->count();
```

**Edit:** After testing, the first method does not work, but the second method will work fine.

Comment: With first(), error is the same. Yes I think I will use QueryBuilder ...

Comment: And you prefer QueryBuilder or Eloquent ?

Comment: It depends on what I'm doing. For the most part, I use Eloquent because there's a bit of extra functionality, such as collection methods. There are times, however, when I use the QueryBuilder methods.

Comment: Another question, with QueryBuilder, it is possible to call a SQL function ?

Comment: You should be able to, with either the `select` or `statement` functions